# In VS2013 why does the Configuration Manager only show debug as an option for websites?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In VS2013 why does the Configuration Manager only show debug as an option for websites?

Attaching image to show what I'm talking about.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Configuration Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Website projects are not based on MSBuild (there's no .csproj or .vbproj).  Configuration is an MSBuild concept, so it doesn't apply to these projects; but since they show up, they appear as Debug by default.